# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as a python module and ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I'm try to deploy virtual host my django project into apache2 via mod_wsgi WSGIDaemon method, i'm using ubuntu 16.04 and i'm getting following error.

**From apache2 error log:**

> [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.748517 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821891782400] [remote ::1:44748] mod_wsgi (pid=14231): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.748570 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821891782400] [remote ::1:44748] mod_wsgi (pid=14231): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py'.
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.748639 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821891782400] [remote ::1:44748] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.748657 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821891782400] [remote ::1:44748]   File "/var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py", line 12, in 
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.748662 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821891782400] [remote ::1:44748]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.748677 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821891782400] [remote ::1:44748] ImportError: No module named 'django'
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.787336 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821849777920] [remote ::1:38604] mod_wsgi (pid=14231): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.787379 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821849777920] [remote ::1:38604] mod_wsgi (pid=14231): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py'.
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.787447 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821849777920] [remote ::1:38604] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.787465 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821849777920] [remote ::1:38604]   File "/var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py", line 12, in 
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.787470 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821849777920] [remote ::1:38604]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>   [Tue Dec 11 11:55:31.787484 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14231:tid 139821849777920] [remote ::1:38604] ImportError: No module named 'django'

**In my host file 000-default.conf:**

ServerName www.rasa_django.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rasa_django
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined

```
Alias /static /var/www/html/rasa_django/static

<Directory /var/www/html/rasa_django/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess rasa_django.com python-path=/var/www/html/rasa_django python-home=/home/aarbor_01/env_site1/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup rasa_django.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/rasa_django/rasa_django/wsgi.py
```

**Here my wsgi.py file:**

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'rasa_django.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm cleared the issue by folling link https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/378

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#daemon-mode-single-application), if you're using a virtual environment (which I'm assuming `env_site1` is), then you should point `python-home` to the root of that environment.

Try:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess rasa_django.com python-path=/var/www/html/rasa_django python-home=/home/aarbor_01/env_site1
```

Comment: @Aarbor1 what version of mod_wsgi are you using?

Comment: I'm using mod-wsgi==4.6.5 version